# Gzip string unable to concatenate to a string

Tags: html, c++, linux, http, gzip

I'm a newbie in c++ and I've been trying to search for an answer to this question but can hardly found an answer I'm trying to compress an html string body with zlib in gzip compression the compression gets done successfully but when I try to concatenate it to another string it won't concatenate at all rendering the body to be blank here is the compression code:

```
void compress_message(){
            z_stream zs;
            char outbuffer[32768];
            long strlen = content.size();
            int ret;
            string outstring;

            memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

            if (deflateInit2(&zs, 
                     Z_BEST_COMPRESSION,
                     Z_DEFLATED,
                     MOD_GZIP_ZLIB_WINDOWSIZE + 16, 
                     MOD_GZIP_ZLIB_CFACTOR,
                     Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY) != Z_OK
            ) {
                throw(std::runtime_error("deflateInit2 failed while compressing."));
            }

            content = "";

            zs.next_in = (Bytef*) content.data();
            zs.avail_in = strlen;

            do {
                //cout << "compressing..." << endl;
                zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(outbuffer);
                zs.avail_out = sizeof(outbuffer);

                ret = deflate(&zs, Z_FINISH);

                if (content.size() < zs.total_out) {
                    // append the block to the output string
                    content.append(outbuffer,
                                     zs.total_out - content.size());
                }
            } while (ret == Z_OK);

            deflateEnd(&zs);
            //cout << "original: " << content << endl;
            if (ret != Z_STREAM_END) {          // an error occurred that was not EOF
                ostringstream oss;
                oss << "Exception during zlib compression: (" << ret << ") " << zs.msg;
                throw(std::runtime_error(oss.str()));
            }
        }
```

base64 conversion function:

```
string tobase64(string data) {
    string code64,
        output = "";
    int i = 0,
        j = 0;
    unsigned int slen = data.size();
    const char* bytes_to_encode;
    code64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
             "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             "0123456789+/";
    unsigned char char_array_3[3],
        char_array_4[4];

    bytes_to_encode = data.c_str();

    while(slen--){
        char_array_3[i++] = bytes_to_encode[j++];

        if(3 == i){
            char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
            char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                output += code64[char_array_4[i]];
            }

            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i)
    {
        for(j = i; j < 3; j++)
            char_array_3[j] = '\0';

        char_array_4[0] = ( char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
        char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
        char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);

        for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
          output += code64[char_array_4[j]];

        while((i++ < 3))
          output += '=';
    }

    return output;
}
```

the string is successfully compressed but when I concatenate it to the string response like:

```
string final_content = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"+headers+"\r\n\r\n");
content = tobase64(content);
final_content += content;
```

I also tried

```
final_content.append(content);
```

They both have the same result the body is never concatenated the final_content when printed only shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-type: text/html
```

and the compressed string is never included have been trying to find answers online and couldn't figure it out please help. I'm working this on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Shouldn't it be base64 encoded for an HTML document?

Comment: @stark ah so after the gzip compression the result should then be encoded to base 64? have not tried that yet will try that here

Comment: @stark tried base64 conversion but I got the same result I still can't concatenate the resulting string in base64 I have attached my base64 converter function as well on the update

Comment: It kind of looks like you are setting `content` to an empty string in the middle of the compress message function before it's used as input to `zs`